# Variadic template type deduction

Tags: c++11

I came accross this question when I wanted to split a variadic template parameter pack into two parts, the first containing all elements but the last and a second one containing only the last one. A straight forward implementation, which came to my mind, was the `invoke1` function in the following example:

```
template <typename... Ts>
void invoke1(Ts... ts, int param) {
}

template <typename... Ts>
void invoke2(int param, Ts... ts) {
}

int main() {    
    invoke1(1); // this works
    invoke2(1); // this works

    invoke1(1, 2, 3); // this does not work
    invoke1<int, int>(1, 2, 3); // this works
    invoke2(1, 2, 3); // this works

    return 0;
}
```

Why are the template parameters not deduced for `invoke1` when the template parameter pack is specified first? Would it create ambiguities in type deduction?

Answer (score 2):

```
template <typename... Ts>
void invoke1(Ts... ts, int param) {
}
```

First of all, why does

```
invoke1<int, int>(1, 2, 3);
```

work? The above specifies the types explicitly, so no type deduction is required. The template is instantiated as:

```
void invoke1(int, int, int);
```

so a call with `(1, 2, 3)` now becomes perfectly valid.

On the other side if you don't specify the types explicitly, the compiler has no way to know where the parameter pack ends. 
Is it `invoke1(int, int, int, int);` or `invoke1(int, int, int);`?

Now, you'll say: "Can't it just take the last given parameter and end the parameter pack before it?". Well, the answer is **no**.

`invoke2` on the other hand works fine, because it's clear where the parameter pack starts and ends.

As a rule of thumb, always put the parameter pack last.

Comment: > Now, you'll say: "Can't it just take the last given parameter and end the parameter pack before it?". Well, the answer is no.

Why is the answer no? That was my main question.

Comment: @Jodebo Because that is how the feature was specified and standardized.

Comment: But IMHO a lot of things in the standard are made the way that ‘it just works’. My question is, why can’t the compiler deduce the template arguments? What’s the reason against it? Would it create ambiguities in type deduction, etc.? Or is it just a language defect and no one has submitted a paper?

Comment: @Jodebo The standard only specifies that such a scenario is a non-deduced context. I also looked up the proposals for variadic templates but they don't give a reason either. If someone finds a nice source, feel free to edit the question.